# insert into without error but not inserting. + more intuitive syntax?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to insert data into a table created with SQLite. Most of the code is converting my arrays into one  string for con.excute(). Maybe this is the problem? Is there a better way? No error returned.

```
def add_row(table, columns, values):
    con = sql_connection("database.db")
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    # column list to string
    if isinstance(columns, list) == True:
        columns = ", ".join(columns)
    # wrap each string in list with '' and convert whole list to string
    if isinstance(values, list) == True:
        for i in range(0, len(values)):
            if isinstance(values[i], str) == True:
                values[i] = "'" + values[i] + "'"
        values = ", ".join(values)
    try:
        cmd = "insert into " + table + "(" + columns + ") values (" + values + ")"
        print(cmd)
        cursorObj.execute(cmd)
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])

add_row("Stocks", ["symbol", "name"], ["TEST", "test"])
```

print(cmd) output:

```
insert into Stocks (symbol, name) values ('TEST', 'test')
```

CLARIFICATION: I'm not worried about security concerns. It will only ever be used locally.

Comment: Maybe try with capitals, or adding a semicolon at the end?

Comment: [*Do not*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) build a command using string concatenation.

Comment: You aren't sanitizing any of your input values. Simply wrapping a value in single quotes isn't sufficient if a value *contains* a single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Note what others have said: such a general function should not be used online as makes the database vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. However, my database is, and will always be, local.

```
def add_row(table, columns, values):
    valueArr = []
    if (len(columns) == len(values)) == False:
        print("Values and columns must be of equal length")
        return
    columns = ", ".join(columns)
    for value in values:
        valueArr.append("?")
    valueArr = ", ".join(valueArr)
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as con:
        try:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cmd = "insert into " + table + " (" + columns + ")  values (" + valueArr + ")"
            print("cmd", cmd)
            cursor.execute(cmd,
                           values)
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])

add_row("Stocks", ["symbol", "name", "exchange"], ["AAPL", "Apple", "NASDAQ"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend trying to generalize this function for arbitrary tables and columns.

```
def add_symbol_and_name(symbol, name):
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into Stocks (symbol, name) values (?, ?)",
                       (symbol, name))
```

Anything more dynamic than this opens you up to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).